# Is this possible to do in ionic?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to develop an app and I have chosen ionic because I need to do both, ios and web but I am not sure if I wil be able.

This would be the app:

[image]

As you can see I need to show a map with different placeholder and when you click in some it would appear a box. Do you think ionic have the tools and the power to achieve this?

The way to map the placeholders in html would be with position absolute and coordinate x and y but I don't think this is a good way

Thank you

Comment: Cordova provides a "web view" in which you run the application. So, if this works in the browser on the mobile device, it should also work in Cordova. (Ionic is a framework that uses Cordova).

Comment: Yes, I know but that is the weak point of ionic in this case. To get the elements on the image and make it interactive

Comment: Well, from my point of view, ionic has nothing to do with this. It all comes to what you can do (css, animations, javascript). If you can work with those, than you can do this. It's not ionic, it's the browser installed on that mobile.